# How to design a control loop

Tags: c++, posix, software-design

This is more a software design question, so it should be independent of language - but for completeness let's assume C++ and a POSIX system.

What I try to achieve:

- Read out low level sensors, over I2C and 1W protocol (All readout's need time but not necessarily a lot of resources CPU/Memory wise) / The readout frequency is different for all the devices.
- Feedback the read information (feedback frequency is faster than the slowest sensor)
- Be responsive when a new command comes (over Bluetooth (bluez))

**How would I best do this?**

What I have now is that I create objects out of the sensors with the same super class with a `ptreath` measurement loop in it with write to recent value parameter and a main loop constantly reading from the last value.

This seems to me rather clumsy since I have to look the variables etc. Is there a better/easier way to achieve this? The feedback algorithm is rather straight forward and doesn't need a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to instantiate measurement-messages in the sensor-poll threads and queue them all up, on one producer-consumer queue, to one thread that runs a state-machine that implements the control algorithm/s.  The control messages can also get shoved onto the queue and so get handled correctly in the same manner.

This keeps all the complex control decisions in one thread, one state-engine, where the operation can be easily debugged message-by-message.

The main thread could wait on the PC queue and operate the SM.  The blocking PC queue eliminates pointless, wasteful and avoidable var polling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To me it always seemed to be a bit of an overkill to make a treath per sensor. But maybe it is the best/cleanest way to do it.